# PHP - How to make php.net's sample code not hang?

Tags: php, sockets, client

The [Simple TCP/IP client](https://www.php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php) example will hang if no data is being received.

To see what I mean, copy the client code and run it, but remove one of the \r\n's in the GET request to make it invalid, so it looks like this:

```
$in =  "HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$in .= "Host: www.example.com\r\n";
$in .= "Connection: Close\r\n";
```

The server won't respond, which is normal, but I want to be able to have a timeout or a way to keep it from hanging.

I've tried setting the timeout using socket_set_option but I think that only applies to socket_connect.

Anyone have a solution?

If I use **socket_recv** with a MSG_DONTWAIT flag, what is the proper way to wait for all data, connection close, or a timeout if neither of those occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`socket_select()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-select.php) to determine if a socket has data to be read.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't notice that function on the php.net site, thanks.